# Java UDP packet size alignment

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I am writing a program in java using sockets with UDP. For a number of reasons i am seeking to align the sizes of each UDP packet so they are uniform, i.e. each one is always (predefined) XYZ KB in size regardless of actual payload (which could be much less). How might this be easily achieved (via padding bytes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocate a fixed size byte array, fill it with whatever data you have, then create a datagram packet from it.

Comment: Thanks so much. I'm not worried about truncation at this stage as the real payload will be always smaller than the byte array size.